# Unresponsive UI elements become responsive after resize

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, responsive-design

I'm experiencing a weird UI bug where when I click on an element, can be a drop-down list or button, it is unresponsive. If I then resize the screen and click the element again, it is responsive. I haven't found a good explanation for why or how this is occurring. And it doesn't affect all elements on the relevant screen.
I have a front end using Bourbon SASS on a rails application. On some pages, I have jquery javascript, but on others, it is just HTML and CSS. The browser can be chrome or explorer.
I'd appreciate any insight into this issue. Let me know if I need to provide more information.

Here is the partial of the form that is affected. The second drop down element is unresponsive unless I maximize the screen.

```
<div class="send-invite-container">

  <%= form_for :send_invite, url: admin_send_invite_url do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label "First Name" %>
      <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label "Last Name" %>
      <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
   </div>

   <div class="field">
     <%= f.label "Email" %>
     <%= f.text_field :email %>
   </div>

   <div class="field">
     <%= f.label "Client" %>
     <%=f.collection_select(:requested_organization, @client_collection, :name, :name)%>
   </div>

   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Associated Company" %>
    <%=f.select(:parent_role, options_for_select([["Company 1", "company_1"], ["Company 2", "company_2"], ["Other", "other"]]))%>
   </div>

   <div class="field">
     <%= f.label "Roles" %>
     <%= f.select(:requested_roles, Role::ROLES, {},
{ :multiple => true, :size => 6 }
) %>
   </div>

    <%= button_tag(type: "submit", class: "btn btn-success") do %>
      <i class="icon-leaf"></i> Send Invite
    <% end %>
  <%end%>

</div>
```

Comment: It sounds like the DOM needs something to trigger the JS. Are you running the JS after `window.load` or something like that? Also, is any of this custom JS or is it all part of some plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. There was a div element that was floating over the select box. The element was defined in the layout html file.